# Pass whole incoming data to curl - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-8, php-curl

I wanted to pass the whole incoming data (that is, `$request`) to the curl not wanted to post to a particular field in the endpoint as `subjectId=>1` as am running this curl request for different endPoint everytime. The below curl request will work  if  `CURLOPT_URL  => $url .  $subjectId`, was given. As my input changes for every end point, i've to pass everything that comes in the input to the curl , i can't pass it as an arary `$subjectId`. Is there any way to do this?

Currently, `dd($Response);` returns `null`

Am giving a postman input like this:

```
{
   "subjectId":"1"
}
```

**Curl**

```
public function getContentqApiPost(Request $request) 
    {
        $token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.ey";
        $headers = [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
        ];
       
          $url="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/courses/course-per-subject";
        $subjectId = "?subjectId=$request->subjectId";
        $ch = curl_init();
        $curlConfig = array(
         //   CURLOPT_URL            => $url . $subjectId,
         CURLOPT_URL            => $url . $request,
            
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers, 
        );
         
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
        
        $result = trim(curl_exec($ch));
       
        $Response = json_decode($result, true);
        
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
            echo $error_msg;
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        return $Response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to pass all params of $request to curl:

```
$queryParams  = '';
$delimeter = '?';
foreach($request->all() as $k => $v){
    $queryParams .= "$delimeter$k=$v";
    $delimeter = '&';
}
```

Also You can only pass the params you want:

```
foreach($request->only(['subjectId']) as $k => $v){
    // code here
}
```

Finally you have:

```
CURLOPT_URL            => $url . $queryParams,
```

Comment: Check `http_build_query()` built in PHP function.

Answer (score -1):

### Answer

Assuming you want to pass the entire GET query string as-is:

```php
$query_string = str_replace($request->url(), "", $request->fullUrl());
$url = "http://localhost:9000/api/courses/course-per-subject" . $query_string;
```

This works because [`$request->url()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_url) returns the URL without the query string parameters, while [`$request->fullUrl()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_fullUrl) returns the URL with all the query string parameters, so we can use `str_replace` with an empty replacement to remove the non-query part. Note that `$query_string` will already start with a `?` so there is no need to add that yourself.

---

### Other suggestions

Unless your Laravel API is a 1:1 copy of the backend API, I strongly suggest writing a class that interfaces with the backend API, then provide it to your Laravel controllers using [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#automatic-injection). E.g.

```php
class CourseCatalogApi {
   public function getSubjectsInCourse(String $course){
       ... // your curl code here
   }
}
```

Finally, since you are already using Laravel, there is no need to write such low level code using curl to make HTTP requests. Consider using [guzzlehttp](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), which is already a dependency of Laravel.